# How to make Netbeans use single quotes in HTML tag attribute autocomplete?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.7

When I type attribute in tag Netbeans automatically add two quotes:

```
<form method="|">
```

I want to make it use single quotes:

```
<form method='|'>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm afraid, but it's pretty sure that double quotes are hard-coded into NetBeans.

Comment: I wish we could. You can try adding a macro/snippet, but that won't seamlessly integrate with the editor though.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer to a very [similar question](/questions/16263616/how-to-force-netbeans-html-autocompletion-to-use-double-quotes-instead-of-single/18056874#18056874):

Type something like `<div class=` now your cursor should be in between two quote or double quote characters. You can now type the other type of quote character and it will change your preference.